# text-overflow:ellipsis for the first line when line breaks

Tags: css, html, text

I have a div with CSS:

```
div.c
{
font-size: 18px;
color: #888;
max-width: 300px;
display: inline-block;
overflow: hidden;
line-height: 20px;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
word-break: break-all;
}
```

`The content in this div is "Abcdef abcdefabcdefabcdefabcdefaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa" //for example, given only to show length in div`.

But if the above `CSS` is used, div content will be broken and also without `three dots //as of text-overflow: ellipsis;`. If i remove `word-break: break-all;` then two lines will be formed with first word on first line and second on second. But `text-overflow: ellipsis;` works with this.

What can i do to keep all the text on one line and also making `text-overflow: ellpsis;` work?

Thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`white-space: nowrap;` Is what you need I believe.